# Is there a way I can use firebaseUI to populate spinner items like I would do with a ListView or a RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Using childevent listeners worked just fine for populating my spinner from my Firebase real time database but it's not as effective as using firebaseUI.
the documentation covers only recyclerview and listview, but I wanna use it for a spinner.

```
 Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Labs");

        FirebaseListOptions<Labs> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<Labs>().setQuery(query, Labs.class).build();


        FirebaseListAdapter<Labs> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Labs>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(@NonNull View v, @NonNull Labs model, int position) {

            }


        };

        spinner.setAdapter(firebaseListAdapter);
```

I just don't know how to bind my model object with the view here.

Comment: What is happening when you are using this code? You don't have any code in your `populateView` method. Have you also started listening for changes?

Comment: @AlexMamo yeah, that's where my problem is. I've just been doing trial and error with the populateview method there, don't know how to bind it with my model class "Labs"

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @AlexMamo I tried arraylist.model.getLabname(); no compile errors but app crashes on start of that activity

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: @AlexMamo checked the stack trace, there was a "layout cannot be null" error. so I set layout to `R.layout.support_simple_dropdown_item`, it doesn't crash anymore but now the spinner doesn't generate any data

Comment: Have you also started listening for changes, like `firebaseListAdapter.startListening()` in `onStart()` method?

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks for this , working now. used the `lifecycyleowner` method instead but I need this

Comment: I have also added it as an aswer to help also future visitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in your code. First, you are getting the following error:

```
layout cannot be null
```

Because you aren't assigning any layout in your `populateView()` method. In your code, this method is empty. So you should create a custom layout that can contain a `TeexView` for each element will help you solve this problem.

The second issue is that you are using `FirebaseListAdapter` but don't listen for changes anywhere. To solve this, please use the following line of code in your `onStart()` method:

```
firebaseListAdapter.startListening();
```

Don't also forget to remove it once is not needed by adding the following lines of code in your `onStop()` method:

```
if(firebaseListAdapter != null) {
    firebaseListAdapter.stopListening();
}
```

Comment: although, that layout didn't work. I had to create a layout with Textviews for each database element I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You would have two options:
one is  just initialize your ArrayAdapter by the list of data you got from query

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,querylistData);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Second you can bind data to the textview  like below:

```
FirebaseListAdapter<Labs> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Labs>(this, Labs.class ,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, query) {
   protected void populateView(View v,Lab model, int position)
     { 


         ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(model.getName());

     }
 };
 spinner.setAdapter(firebaseListAdapter);
```

Comment: the second option generated a no layout error, i fixed it, but then the spinner doesn't show any data now, 
I don't quite understand the "querylistdata" in the first

Comment: I mean by  querlistdata is the list of data you are getting from Firebasedatabase and you want to display in spinner. For second option, I have already edited the code above and you just follow the code and just try this code. hope it show spinner with data